# Conditional formatting custom formula not working as intended

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

```
=NOT(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AT2,INDIRECT("workpattern"))))>0)
```

I want this formula to return `TRUE` if the text string in `AT2` doesn't match any of the text strings in the named range `workpattern`.

I only want the formula to return `TRUE` if a string is an exact match, but it is doing it for partial matches.

For example, where `workpattern` contains `"36 Hours"`, the formula will return

1. `FALSE` where `AT2="36 Hoursxx"` *(which is what I want)*
2. `TRUE` where  `AT2="36 Hou"` *(which I don't want)*

How can modify the formula so it doesn't return TRUE for partial matches?

Answer (score 1):

## FORMULAS

---

### 1.   MATCH Function

```
 # SUCCESS = TRUE  
 =IFERROR(MATCH(AT2,INDIRECT("workpattern")),0)

 # FAILURE = TRUE
 =IFERROR(NOT(MATCH(AT2,INDIRECT("workpattern"))),1)
```

### 2.   SEARCH Function

```
 # SUCCESS = TRUE  
 =IFERROR(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"",""& JOIN("",INDIRECT("workpattern")) &""))

 # FAILURE = TRUE
 =IFERROR(NOT(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"",""& JOIN("",INDIRECT("workpattern")) &"")),1)
```

## EXPLANATIONS

---

### 1.   MATCH Function

The MATCH function returns the relative position of an item in a range that matches a specified value and is better suited to your task.
`MATCH(search_key, range, [search_type])`

- Both MATCH and NOT(MATCH) will always return a **#N/A** error where there is no match.
- NOT(MATCH) is used only to convert a successful MATCH to FALSE.
- IFERROR converts unsuccessful matches to either a `0` (FALSE), or `1` (TRUE) depending on the use case (MATCH vs. NOT(MATCH).

```
 # SUCCESS = TRUE  
 =IFERROR(MATCH(AT2,INDIRECT("workpattern")),0)

 # FAILURE = TRUE
 =IFERROR(NOT(MATCH(AT2,INDIRECT("workpattern"))),1)
```

### 2.   SEARCH Function

Search finds ***a text string*** that also appears in ***another text string***
`SEARCH(search_for, text_to_search, [starting_at])`

Its arguments **do not** support arrays or ranges but the JOIN function can be used to combine an array or range into a single text string.
`JOIN(delimiter, value_or_array1, [value_or_array2, …])`

- To avoid partial matches, the beginning and end of both SEARCH arguments must be delimited with a unique string.  In the example, I used the emoji `""`.
- The same delimiter is used in the JOIN function `JOIN("", array)`
- Both SEARCH and NOT(SEARCH) will always return a **#VALUE!** error when the search string is not found.
- NOT(SEARCH) is used only to convert a successful SEARCH to FALSE.
- IFERROR converts failed searches to either a `0` (FALSE), or `1` (TRUE) depending on the use case (SEARCH vs. NOT(SEARCH).

###### Delimited Formula

```
# SUCCESS = TRUE 
=IFERROR(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"", ""& INDIRECT("workpattern") &""))

# FAILURE = TRUE 
=IFERROR(NOT(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"", ""& INDIRECT("workpattern")) &""), 1)
```

###### Delimited and JOIN

```
# SUCCESS = TRUE 
=IFERROR(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"", ""& JOIN("", INDIRECT("workpattern")) &""))

# FAILURE = TRUE 
=IFERROR(NOT(SEARCH(""& AT2 &"", ""& JOIN("", INDIRECT("workpattern")) &"")),1)
```